# add tags to image in database based on id

Tags: php, mysql, image, keyword

In the database I created (MySQL), there are 2 tables: images and keywords. I managed to upload several PNG images and store their paths to this database in order to retrieve them efficiently, using PHP. Now I want to create some keywords to every image in order to taxinomize them (eg: color, cost, release year etc) and later retrieve an image based on the keyword I'm querying. I have more than 500 images, so adding the keywords manually to each image separately is probably a bad idea. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this? A very common technique I keep seeing is Exif Data, but it is not used in PNG files. Thanks

Comment: Although I tend to avoid it because it's a little unwieldy, an EAV model may be appropriate here.

Comment: Do you have some other data source where this info is stored? Without that you are out of luck, I guess

Comment: @Soana what do you mean by other data source? I only store the data I have in the database. Should I do something else?